# Change table data value color depending on value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to JS. I am trying to change the text color on a table cell depending on the value: Y or N.
I have tried everything on the internet and nothing seems to work.

This is the table data that I am trying to format

```js
function changeValue(bool) {
    if (bool) {
        return "Y";
    } else {
        return "N";
    }
}

var els = document.getElementsByClassName('colorText');
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        var cell = els[i];
    if (cell.textContent === "N") {
        cell.classList.remove('red');
    } if (cell.textContent === "Y") {
        cell.classList.remove('green');
    } 
}
```

```html
<td class="centered colorText">{changeValue(someValue)}</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method for all your `td's` with the class `colorText`

**Using defined CSS classes**

Also use `toggle` instead of `add` or `remove` methods. `toggle` is way simpler and easy to use with click events if you have any.

In addition, to use `td` you need to wrap them in a `table` to work properly.

**Live Demo**

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('.colorText');
  els.forEach(function(cell) {
    if (cell.textContent === "N") {
      cell.classList.toggle('red');
    }
    if (cell.textContent === "Y") {
      cell.classList.toggle('green');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="centered colorText">Y</td>
    <td class="centered colorText">N</td>
    <td class="centered colorText">Y</td>
    <td class="centered colorText">N</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Using JS DOM CSS method**

You can also use `.style` method to `color` your text depending on the textContent **instead** of using custom CSS classes.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('.colorText');
  els.forEach(function(cell) {
    if (cell.textContent === "N") {
      cell.style.color = 'red';
    }
    if (cell.textContent === "Y") {
      cell.style.color = 'green';
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="centered colorText">Y</td>
    <td class="centered colorText">N</td>
    <td class="centered colorText">Y</td>
    <td class="centered colorText">N</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I pasted only the td tag but the table is ok with table head and body and everything. The problem is it doesn't recognise the classes red and green (it says unused css selector)

Comment: @alexxa Hi, You need to define CSS as well. to make sure the CSS is applied as well. Just like i have done in my answer. Let me know

Comment: I defined it :) but no changes yet

Comment: @alexxa Please check my updated answer. I added the DOM css method instead of using CSS classes. Let me know

Comment: @alexxa both methods are working in my answer here. Use the exact Javascript and HTML i have provided and let me know. Otherwise please add your complete HTML code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220263/discussion-between-alwayshelping-and-alexxa).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code.

I am assuming that you already have a css file with the class 'red' and 'green'.

```js
function changeValue(bool) {
        if (bool) {
            return "Y";
        } else {
            return "N";
        }
    }


        var els = document.getElementsByClassName('colorText');
            for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
                var cell = els[i];
            if (cell.textContent === "N") {
                cell.classList.remove('red');//I am not sure if you mean to color the text green if it says "N"
                cell.classList.add('green')
            } if (cell.textContent === "Y") {
                cell.classList.remove('green');
                cell.classList.add('red')
            } 
    }
```

```html
<td class="centered colorText">Y</td>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but it doesn't work :(...The colors are less important. Right now the text color is default color: black

Answer (score 1):

You need to set proper HTML table before getting TD tag

```js
function changeValue(bool) {
    if (bool) {
        return "Y";
    } else {
        return "N";
    }
}

var els = document.getElementsByClassName('colorText');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  var cell = els[i];
  if (cell.textContent === "N") {
    cell.classList.remove('red');
  } if (cell.textContent === "Y") {
    console.log('boom');
    cell.classList.remove('green');
  } 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="colorText">X</td>
    <td class="colorText">Y</td>
    <td class="colorText">Z</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow a single `td` tag is not working as expected. I used `span` and it worked.

```js
function changeValue(bool) {
        if (bool) {
            return "Y";
        } else {
            return "N";
        }
    }


        var els = document.getElementsByClassName('colorText');
            for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
                var cell = els[i];
            if (cell.textContent === "N") {
                cell.classList.remove('green');
                cell.classList.add('red');
            } if (cell.textContent === "Y") {
                cell.classList.remove('red');
                cell.classList.add('green');
            } 
    }
```

```css
.green { color:green; }
.red { color:red; }
```

```html
<span class="centered colorText">Y</span>
```

**Update:**

When I use proper `table`, `tr` and `td`, it working.

```js
function changeValue(bool) {
        if (bool) {
            return "Y";
        } else {
            return "N";
        }
    }


        var els = document.getElementsByClassName('colorText');
            for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
                var cell = els[i];
            if (cell.textContent === "N") {
                cell.classList.remove('green');
                cell.classList.add('red');
            } if (cell.textContent === "Y") {
                cell.classList.remove('red');
                cell.classList.add('green');
            } 
    }
```

```css
.green { color:green; }
.red { color:red; }
```

```html
<table><tr><td class="centered colorText">Y</td></tr></table>
```